# unable to install elementary on asus x205ta

Tags: system-installation

hi everyone I hope for your help. i am trying to install elementary on my asus x205ta without getting results, i follow the guide on the elementary site but i don't get any results. I also tried other guides but in all cases after installation, when the pc starts it takes me to the bios screen as if there were no os on the ssd. if anyone could help me I would be grateful, thanks and have a good time.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Elementary OS is a bit too heavy for your computer. This is a comparison of [the eOS Recommended Hardware](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#download-elementary-os) against your Asus:

|  | Recommendation | Asus X205TA | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CPU | Recent Intel i3 or comparable dual-core 64-bit processor | 1.33-GHz Intel Atom Z3735 CPU | Insufficient |
| Memory | 4 GB | 2 GB | Insufficient Memory |
| Storage | 15 GB (SSD) | 32 GB (eMMC) | Slow, but sufficient |
| Display | 1024x768 (SVGA) | 1366x768 (WXGA) | Sufficient |

While it certainly possible to use Elementary on a system like this with a great deal of post-installation tweaking via the command-line in a Live Session, it would require a remarkable knowledge of the inner workings of GDK, the Linux kernel, and your hardware limitations. It's not something that most people will do.

That said, if you would like to use a modern version of Linux on your Asus notebook, you may want to consider [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org), [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/), or — one of my favourite light-weight distros — [Bohdi Linux](https://www.bodhilinux.com/). These are all based on Ubuntu, just like Elementary OS, and receive regular updates.

Comment: thank you so much I will try with xubuntu